# How to ignore one file in gitignore while unignoring its parent folder

Tags: git, unity-game-engine, gitignore

I want to ignore everything in my project except for

1. *.gitignore* file
2. *Assets* folder
3. *ProjectSettings* folder

Additionally I want to ignore one file *ProjectSettings/ProjectSettings.asset*

---

I searched around and wrote this in my gitignore file:

```
# Ignore Everything
/*

# Except for these:
!/.gitignore
!/Assets
!/ProjectSettings

# Ignore just ProjectSettings
!/ProjectSettings/*
/ProjectSettings/ProjectSettings.asset
```

---

The problem is it is still including *ProjectSettings/ProjectSettings.asset* in my commits. How can I ignore this file while un-ignoring its parent folder?

Comment: Basically, gitignore will not track the files you put in the gitignore, but if you are already tracking them, you need to untrack them to get it to work. Notice that you need to commit before executing these commands, as they will otherwise delete your existing changes.

```git rm -rf --cached . && git add .```

Comment: @Fredrik thanks I will try this and see if it helps in future syncs.

Comment: that's it. it was caching the file. ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Removing the file from `git chached`:

```
$ git rm --cached ProjectSettings/ProjectSettings.asset
```

Comment: that's it. it was caching the file. ty